# Address Book Tutorial

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have been working with [a c# tutorial for beginners to create an address book](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZoDmeAZAD8&feature=relmfu). I followed the instructions, and I have encountered two problems.

1. When I select the properties of the Listview box the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event is missing. I have restarted and refreshed the program several times. I have wrote directly to the file, and it is still not present.
2. When selecting a contact from the list, the text boxes do not reflect the selection. I suspect that this is related to the absence of the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event in the ui. This persisted even when I set [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event in code.

All help would be greatly appreciated.  My code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;


namespace AddressBook
{
    public partial class AddressBook : Form
    {
        public AddressBook()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        private void AddressBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Joe"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Address Book - Joe");
            if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Joe\\settings.xml"))
                File.Create((path + "\\Address Book - Joe\\settings.xml"));
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.FirstName = txtFName.Text;
            p.Address = txtAddress.Text;
            p.City = txtCity.Text;
            p.State = comboState.Text;
            p.ZipCode = txtZip.Text;
            p.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            p.PhoneNumber = txtPhone.Text;
            p.Additional = rtxtAdd.Text;
            people.Add(p);
            listView1.Items.Add(p.FirstName);
            txtFName.Text = "";
            txtAddress.Text = "";
            txtCity.Text = "";
            comboState.Text = "";
            txtZip.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtPhone.Text = "";
            rtxtAdd.Text = "";

        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFName.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].FirstName;
            txtAddress.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address;
            txtCity.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].City;
            comboState.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].State;
            txtZip.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].ZipCode;
            txtEmail.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
            txtPhone.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].PhoneNumber;
            txtZip.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].ZipCode;
            rtxtAdd.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Additional;

        }

        private void txtFName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Additional { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to click the lightning-bolt icon in the Properties window to go to the Events tab.
There, you will see the `SelectedIndexChanged` event (assuming you selected the right control.

You need to bind your handler to that event in order for your code to run.

Comment: @webby68 - At the start of that video, you can see the lightning-bolt is already selected.

Comment: Ok, thanks this is exactly what I needed.  I just simply missed such a small detail.  Thanks so much.  This did fix the problem.

Comment: @webby68 Then you should accept SLaks's answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged` might be listed in the Properties window as **OnSelectedIndexChanged**.
Once you get that event handler working, the textboxes should be populated with the value as expected.

Comment: No; it isn't.  That's a protected virtual method.